# describe file format throws error in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to describe a file format . Syntax seems to be fine , but it throws below error.

[throws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLHhs.png)

I am executing the sql in the same database ,schema with the same role and account that I have used to create the file format. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: remove `s` from `formats`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax between the too file format commands are inconsistent

`SHOW FILE FORMATS` [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-file-formats.html)

and

`DESCRIBE FILE FORMAT name` [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc-file-format.html)

you have `DESCRIBE FILE FORMATS` thus the error message is correctly telling you `formats` is unexpected.